# How do I color a simple image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my icon red but without any success. Is there a way to color this icon??

https://www.shareicon.net/logo-social-docker-media-878943

```css
.text-danger {
color: #ff0000
}
```

```html
<h4 class="text-danger"><img class="highlight-icon" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2017/02/15/878943_media_512x512.png"></h4>
```

Comment: Thats not icon, it's an image... you can't just recolour images (well, unless the site dynamically creates them and lets you supply the colour as paramters of course)

Comment: Explain what changes you need to  still make to the div to make it look similar to the icon in the url.

Comment: `color` is for text color. You can not change the color of a rasterized image... you would have to edit it in like Photoshop or something. Or you can use a icon font like FontAwesome

Comment: But how can people edit icons like this one: https://www.bootstrapdash.com/demo/star-admin-free/index.html  Those are black icons.

Comment: @asfasd: That particular site uses [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Comment: @musefan from the site you can download .ico

Comment: @asfasd because those are not `<img />`'s they are using a icon font like [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Comment: I'm using font-awesome aswell. But I need to recolor that image.

Comment: Not in your code in your question you are not. And the ability to download an .ico is not related to your question

Comment: Export this image as an SVG, and if placed inline in the html page - the color can be edited. See jsfiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ku6fofm/

Comment: @asfasd no you are using an `img` with a `src` of https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2017/02/15/878943_media_512x512.png which is a .png image.... not a font

Comment: @Markie how can I call the svg in the code? <img> doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full example using an inline SVG:

- Export image as SVG
- Place SVG inline in your html
- Add a CSS `fill` to the svg path

  .text-danger svg path {
    fill: #ff0000 !important;
  }

See jsfiddle for full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w1bqpjqs/

Comment: doesn't appear on my google chrome but works on fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this method, SVG would be my personal preference. However just for an alternative answer you can use a css filters to change the icons color. This will not work in IE, but according to caniuse.com it will work in 90% of global browsers:

```css
.highlight-icon{
   filter: hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(100) brightness(75%)
}
```

```html
<h4 class="text-danger"><img class="highlight-icon" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2017/02/15/878943_media_512x512.png"></h4>
```

You can't specify color by hex, but you can play with hue-rotate to change the color, and brightness and saturation to get variation of a color you like (red)